# How do you solve for the compensation resistor in this circuit using Vout?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, dc

[image]

I managed to solve for the value of the compensation resistor (R3 which goes at the positive terminal of the op amp) because I know that R3= R2||R1. I reduced the resistors in the feedback loop of the op amp to 8/3R and took that in parallel with R = (8/11)R which is the right answer.

How do I calculate R3 using Vout due to Ibias as it says in the hint?

With only Ibias active I calculated Vout to be 8*R*Ib. What do I do with this value? How do I mathematically show that R3 should go at the non-inverting terminal of the opamp?

Comment: So if you ground Vin & Vout and Zin(-) = Zin(+)  what is Zin(-)

Comment: R2? R1? I see none of those in your circuit.